# Как отформатировать текст на стороне MS SQL сервера используя массив аргументов?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Используется MS SQL 2019.
В одной таблице сохранены локализованные шаблоны сообщений (например, "An error occurred while processing the file %s.").
В другой таблице сохраняются аргументы в JSON виде, т.к. количество аргументов различается от сообщения к сообщению.
Другими словами, получаем формат строки, получаем аргументы и всё это на стороне клиента форматируем с помощью метода [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).
Передо мной поставили задачу "перенести" форматирование сообщений на сторону MS SQL сервера. С помощью функции [FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) можно форматировать текст, но проблема в том, что количество аргументов различное и каким образом передать массив аргументов непонятно и возможно ли это в принципе?

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '[1,"abc","def"]';

SELECT FORMATMESSAGE (
    'First arg: %s, second arg: %s, last arg: %s',
    JSON_VALUE( @json, '$')
)
-- выводит: First arg: (null), second arg: (null), last arg: (null)

SELECT FORMATMESSAGE (
    'First arg: %s, second arg: %s, last arg: %s',
    JSON_VALUE( @json, '$[0]'),
    JSON_VALUE( @json, '$[1]'),
    JSON_VALUE( @json, '$[2]')
)
-- выводит: First arg: 1, second arg: abc, last arg: def
```

---

Каким образом можно отформатировать текст на стороне MS SQL сервера используя массив аргументов?

Comment: что мешает свою функцию-обертку добавить?

Comment: @teran каким образом? Можно ли в последствии вызывать эту "обёртку" через JDBC? С SQL я на "будьте любезны"...

Comment: В MS SQL есть хранимые процедуры и функции. Последние делятся на скалярные и табличные. Вот вам нужна скалярная функция. Если вы всего хотите ей скармливать JSON массив, то видимо с двумя параметрами, и возврающая строку. Оператор  цикла тоже имеется, Но на крайний случай аргументов у формата всего 20, можно и без цикла обойтисть. Назовете ее `FORMATMSG_JSON` и будете вызывать как `SELECT FORMATMSG_JSON('%s', @x)`

Comment: FORMATMESSAGE игнорирует избыток аргументов подстановки. JSON_VALUE тоже не выдаёт ошибку на несуществующий путь. Так что делаешь запрос, куда просто наталкиваешь JSON_VALUE( @json, '$[...]') по максимуму, все 20 штук. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DuiXBAO_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря помощи [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1551810/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-ms-sql-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?noredirect=1#comment2794064_1551810) и [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1551810/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-ms-sql-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?noredirect=1#comment2794098_1551810), создал пользовательскую функцию представленную ниже:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID ( N'dbo.FORMATMESSAGE_JSON', N'FN' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.FORMATMESSAGE_JSON;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FORMATMESSAGE_JSON( @Format nvarchar(MAX), @Json nvarchar(MAX) )
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN FORMATMESSAGE(
                @Format,
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[0]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[1]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[2]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[3]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[4]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[5]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[6]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[7]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[8]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[9]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[10]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[11]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[12]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[13]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[14]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[15]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[16]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[17]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[18]' ),
                JSON_VALUE( @Json, '$[19]' )
            )
END;
```

Используется тривиально:

```sql
SELECT dbo.FORMATMESSAGE_JSON(
            '1 arg: %s, 2 arg: %s, 3 arg: %s',
            '[1,"abc","def"]'
        );
```

Функция ожидает строковое представление JSON-массива, т.е. для передачи подструктуры необходимо воспользоваться [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```sql
SELECT dbo.FORMATMESSAGE_JSON(
            '1 arg: %s, 2 arg: %s, 3 arg: %s',
            JSON_QUERY( '{"args":[1,"abc","def"]}', '$.args' )
        );
```

Буду рад предложениям и конструктивной критике.

---

##### Ссылки по теме

- [Функция FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Описание синтаксиса форматирования в FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#msg_str)
- [MS SQL функции JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Оператор OPEN_JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Создание пользовательских функций](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)